Cors blocking requests on WebGL build Unity
I made a multiplayer game using Unity and exporting it with WebGL I've ran into an issue. Requests to my remote server blocked by Cors in browser.

access to fetch at 'https://myhost/launch' from origin 'http://localhost:63159' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

When game is exported with desktop profile it works just as intended.
I also launched chrome with no cors and it worked so issue is not on the server.
Solutions I find on the internet are server-sided. I have access to the server but this issue seems to come from browser side not from server side.

CORS issues are usually something to be resolved more server configuration side so check the settings of your local HTTP server where you host your application. Your desktop (standalone) application doesn't have this issue as CORS is more an HTTP server related thing. You host your page on localhost so this server prevents requests to other servers - except the according CORS headers are set-up to allow such a request. This is to protect the user

If you do a web search for 'unity cors' you'll find many resources about this.

There are a number of well documented options, whats best depends on what suits you and what you're doing best.

@derHugo my server is actually already deployed on public domain so it is not localhost if this matters. Actually there are a multitude of ways to resolve cors on Asp.Net core framework my server is running. Ones I've tried yielded no result yet.

Well it is localhost, thats exactly what the error above says.

localhost in the error is the node.js host unity webGL app is running on

@derHugo you were right about the fact this is a problem on the server. Error message is misleading by saying that request was blocked by browser Cors policy not the server Cors policy.

The way I solved this is by manually rerunning application many times and doing what error message says. My mistake was applying response headers using Asp.net core filters. Client makes a preflight request first with OPTIONS method. You need to put headers from "access-control-allow" group client is requiring to the both "OPTIONS" response and main response ("GET" in my case). So I made a middleware that applies headers to all requests. Only then it starts working properly.
